# How to get list of video files from phone storage

Tags: android

I want to get my videos from the "Download" folder in phone storage and put it in my list view ,but I dont know :

1. what I should write in " like?"
2. what I should write in {"%FolderName%"}
3. when I should use the "%" in the below code

I've tried "%Download%" many times, but it's not working,
please help me !

```
String selection=MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA +" like?";
                String[] selectionArgs=new String[]{"%FolderName%"};
                videocursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        parameters, selection, selectionArgs, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");
```